# Oracle SQL - how to Limit the comma splitting to rows

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, rows

I have a data like this,

```
ID      RPT_NAME CSV_STRING
------------------------------
abc123  Test1   AA,BB,AC,AD,EF,GG,FG,FD,DF,GG,AA,PL,KI,LO,TT,TE,LF,FG
abc456  Test2   GF,DS,SA,RE,EW,QQ,QW
def123  Test3   HH
```

I wish to limit the comma splitting to rows for fixed number of commas. Post that, I would take the next set of records, until all the records have been pushed in rows in groups of 6.

For eg, my offset is **5 commas,** 
I am trying to get the output like this,

```
ID      RPT_NAME CSV_STRING
----------------------
abc123  Test1   AA,BB,AC,AD,EF,GG
abc123  Test1   GG,FG,FD,DF,GG,AA
abc123  Test1   PL,KI,LO,TT,TE,LF
abc123  Test1   FG
abc456  Test2   GF,DS,SA,RE,EW,QQ
abc456  Test2   QW
def123  Test3   HH
```

I tried my best to explain it. :)

Can I please get a solution on this? TIA Appreciated

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with tab(ID,RPT_NAME,CSV_STRING) as
(
 select 'abc123','Test1','AA,BB,AC,AD,EF,GG,FG,FD,DF,GG,AA,PL,KI,LO,TT,TE,LF,FG' from DUAL
  union all
 select 'abc456','Test2','GF,DS,SA,RE,EW,QQ,QW' from DUAL
  union all
 select 'def123','Test3','HH' from DUAL
)


 select id,rpt_name,
        trim(trailing ',' from regexp_substr(csv_string,'([^,]+(,|$)){1,6}',1,level))
   from tab
connect by regexp_substr(csv_string,'([^,]+(,|$)){1,6}',1,level) is not null
    and prior id=id and prior dbms_random.value is not null
```

`regexp_substr` with regular expression `([^,]+(,|$)){1,6}` get one to six elements. `connect by` reproduce row until the string is completed.

Comment: you are the best !  :) 
Worked perfectly. That answer\s my question.

Comment: Consider this as my another comment,
one thing that is failing at my end is, 
I have an requirement to add another select on top of this with same logic but for another column, and thats where it failed coz, Clob is being used in group by which is what Oracle doesnt allow.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: @AniruddhaK clob large ? may be convert it in varchar (`dbms_lob.substr()`) in query

Comment: but the length is too big, mnore than 4000 where Varchar2 fails

Comment: @AniruddhaK It is necessary to process parts and combine the results. Or create a stored function that highlights tokens